# JavaScript Keyboard events and comparison

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I wrote a function which should check if one particular button is being pressed. However, it seems to always return false. This is the function:

```
function keyPressed(ev) {
    var r = false;
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        if (ev == e.which || ev == e.keyCode) {
            r = true;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

And this is how you'd call it:

```
if (keyPressed(119)) {
    // do something
}
```

Checking with alert, they seem to be the same number when I press "W", but the function just always returns false. Are they different type?

Answer (score 1):

`document.onkeypress` will be executed each time you press a key. But `keyPressed` will be executed only when you call it. So, except if you launch `keyPressed(touch)` at the same time you're pushing *touch*, it will always return false.

What you did there is: when I call `keyPressed(`), bind a function to  `document.onkeypress`. Then return r, which has not been modified by the binding.

I suggest you try to put a switch-like structure with callbacks in a big `document.onkeypress` function.

Bonus: e.which is deprecated, use e.key if possible.

Comment: I'm actually using the keyPressed -function in a loop which is updated every second. I updated the function to compare "ev" and "e.key", and now it works, kind of. Is there any way to return true or false there?

Comment: What you described sounds like you'll be creating redundant bindings to document every second. You may be headed down the wrong track.

Comment: I second @gfullam, that's a bad practice. You should bind a function to `document.onkeypress` only once, and then update it depending of what you want. Concerning your true/false question, r is unecessary: just replace `r = true` by `return true`. And `return r` by `return false`.